# Unity unable to compile project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, compilation

So I am trying to build my unity game (windows x86) and I get an error saying

`"Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor"`

So I have no idea on how to build my games anymore.

I looked into the error on google which is :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.CameraEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/CameraEditor.cs:363)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1240)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

But I just can't seem to find anything.
Please help me.

Comment: You have a null reference exception at your CameraEditor Script at line 363. So there must be some variable that is null for some reason. Either you fix it so it can't be null or if it CAN be null then you should handle it properly. You could at this part of the code to your question.

Comment: It looks like your project contains scripts have compile error(s). You need to solve those first, then your project will then be able to build. As to which is the offending script, I can't tell based on what you have provided so far.

Comment: @CarlitosJan I may be wrong, but I think `CameraEditor.cs` is part of/provided by Unity. Still, it is correct to say that there some null variable is causing the issue.

Comment: Hello, Unity Engine is a very special case, so depending on the version you use as well as the build type. Is it Unity 2021, 2022 or 2023? Is it Alpha, Beta or Final? and which version exactly? Also, does this happens on one project or other projects as well? Does it happen on an empty project? I would also like an output of of the full Console (preferably text - and yes you can Copy-paste it). You can group by errors so that the same error repeated multiple times doesn't spam. In order to exclude any internal errors, do all this after freshly opening the project. Thanks!

Comment: I am using Unity 5.6.5f1, it is the only version of unity that works for me right now.

Comment: Alright, and regarding the other questions?